# Pyest second browser parameter does not load site from a fixture

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, fixtures

I have a class Pytest fixture that has two parameters `chrome` and `firefox` that will run at a class level.  The first parameter, `chrome`, loads the `load_site` fixture fine but the second parameter, `firefox`, does not load the `load_site` and instead goes directly to the yield and closes the browser.  Not sure what is causing it.  Please help!

It does work if the `load_site` fixture is removed from the class and set in the `test_open_url` with `self.driver.get(MY_LOGIN_PAGE)`.

Unfortunately, I cannot break this out of a class fixture as I need this page to load at the very beginning of every initial test run.

My code is below:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


@pytest.fixture(params=["chrome", "firefox"], scope="class")
def driver_init(request):
    if request.param == "chrome":
        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    if request.param == "firefox":
        web_driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="../resources/drivers/geckodriver")
    request.cls.driver = web_driver
    yield
    web_driver.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope="class", name="load_site")
def load_site(request):
    request.cls.driver.get("MY_LOGIN_PAGE")


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_init", "load_site")
class TestURL:
    def test_open_url(self):
        sleep(2)
```

Comment: There are no errors in your code; most probably the issue is the driver init. Are you sure it's working fine? Try to init the driver outside of the tests, e.g. from terminal: `python -c "from selenium import webdriver; d = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='../resources/drivers/geckodriver')"` and check whether an exception is raised.